# Why isn't my navbar working with html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im new to using html/css. When clicking on "logga in" or "registrera" it's working for transfering me to a new page. But the whole navbar doesn't work at all. I don't know whats wrong as I made another site yesterday where the navbar did work. Can anyone please help me to detect whats wrong??

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="viktigovning.css">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> <span>Logo</span></a>

        <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="omoss.html" class="active"></a>Hem</li>
        <li><a href="omoss.html"></a>Om oss</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Skötselråd</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Bilder</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Kontakta oss</li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="main">
        <a href="omoss.html" class="user"><i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>Logga in</a>
        <a href="#">Registrera</a>
        </div>
    </header> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oxfH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHiVb.png)

Comment: You included your HTML code in your question but not CSS. Why couldn't you add both?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and edit your post to include a [MRE]

Comment: Please include the content in your answers. Pictures of code or output are not helpful as they may not render well on some device, people who have similar questions won't be able to find your question as easily. You will get fewer answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing anchor tag before text

It should be like this

```
<ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="omoss.html" class="active">Hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="omoss.html">Om oss</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skötselråd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bilder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakta oss</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it finally worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a BASE tag which tells the browser the home address from where all relative URLs originate...

```
<head>

  <base href="https://thisplace.com/" target="_blank">

</head>
```

Comment: Then you misdirected us when you claimed the script worked fine on another site, which is why I offered you the BASE tag!